# Email procedure in oracle taking long time to execute

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have the following procedure,

```
PROCEDURE SEND_TO_MAILING_LIST
 (P_MAILING_LIST IN VARCHAR2
 ,P_SUBJECT IN VARCHAR2
 ,P_TEXT IN VARCHAR2
 ,P_STATUS OUT NUMBER
 )
 IS
CURSOR mail_cur IS
SELECT  x.forenames||'.'||x.surname||'@xyz.com' mail_alias
FROM    ABC a, XYZ x
WHERE   a.id = x.id
AND a.list_name = 'DEF'
AND     a.id <> 274
Union All
SELECT  x.forenames||'.'||x.surname||'@abc.com' mail_alias
FROM    ABC a, XYZ x
WHERE   a.id = x.id
AND x.list_name = 'DEF'
AND     a.id = 274
Union All
SELECT x.other_to_email mail_alias
FROM    ABC a, XYZ x
AND a.list_name = 'PQR';
BEGIN
p_status := 1;
FOR rec IN mail_cur LOOP
        MAILX(rec.mail_alias, 'TESTING PURPOSE','TESTING','TEST');
END LOOP;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
p_status  := -1;
END;
```

This on execution is taking 5 minutes to send email to desired people. The individual queries only results in a few rows(less than 5)

What could be the reason for this delay?

Comment: _Without_ the LOOP, the procedure is faster?

Comment: Oracle != MySQL, I removed the extraneous tag.

Comment: Its taking too much time without loop also. Its the issue with the inbuilt mailx proc i guess. Any suggestions to overcome this delay?

Comment: @RamanathanK _" the issue [is] with the inbuilt mailx proc i guess"_ It seems rather easy to check that for sure. If it is so, maybe you have some network-related issue. Something implying the DNS ? Or a issue with the distant mail server ? Could you trace the various SMTP sessions involved using a network analyzer like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) ?

Comment: Just try to execute the SQL separately in sqlplus and then the mailx to find where is the issue

Comment: I tried. The SQl took just a few seconds to execute as expected. But the mailx is taking approx 5-6 mins. Is there any solution?

Comment: Just try to execute the mailx with one mail id as input

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try like the below

```
SELECT  decode(a.list_name,'DEF',x.forenames||'.'||x.surname||decode(a.id,274,'@abc.com','@xyz.com'), x.other_to_email mail_alias)
mail_alias
FROM    ABC a, XYZ x
WHERE   a.id = x.id
AND a.list_name in ('DEF','PQR');
```